# Laravel : Join returning all elements

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My **controller** of a socials table outputs the following :

```
   [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "value": "FaAlgolia",
            "name": "zaefzaef",
            "profile_id": 4,
            "order": 9000,
            "created_at": "2021-05-17 20:25:03",
            "updated_at": "2021-05-17 20:25:03"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "value": "FaAlipay",
            "name": "azdadzzad",
            "profile_id": 4,
            "order": 9000,
            "created_at": "2021-05-17 20:41:53",
            "updated_at": "2021-05-17 20:41:53"
        }
    ]
```

Each of those elements **belongs** to a profile.

**Profiles table :**

[image]

**Socials table :**

[image]

In **profiles** table I have a **URL** column. I would want to return it in my array so the output will look like this.

```
   [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "value": "FaAlgolia",
            "name": "zaefzaef",
            "profile_id": 4,
            "order": 9000,
            "created_at": "2021-05-17 20:25:03",
            "updated_at": "2021-05-17 20:25:03"
            "url": the url from profiles table
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "value": "FaAlipay",
            "name": "azdadzzad",
            "profile_id": 4,
            "order": 9000,
            "created_at": "2021-05-17 20:41:53",
            "updated_at": "2021-05-17 20:41:53"
            "url": the url from profiles table
        }
    ]
```

I tried making a **join** like the following but it returns both elements with all url. So the output is the **first array** with **both urls** then **second element** with **both urls**:

```
public function profile($id)
{
    $data = DB::table('socials')->where('profile_id','=', $id)
    ->join('profiles', 'url', '=', 'profiles.url')
    ->groupBy('profile_id')
    ->get();
    return $data; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Laravel'sk` way is to use Eloquent models to solve your problem.

Your models would look like so.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Social extends Model
{
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Profile::class);
    }
}

class Profile extends Model
{
}
```

From here there is two solutions, the simple is to just include the profile using `with()`,

```
return Social::with('profile')->get();
```

The following structure would be presented.

```
    {
        "id": 4,
        ...
        "profile": {
            "url": the url from profiles table
        }
    },
```

That is not exactly what you wanted, instead you can use an getter in `Laravel`. On your Social model add the following. For the getter to work, it needs to follow the getColumnAttribute function naming. To add the column to the model transformation, add it to the `$appends` `array`.

```
class Social extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['issues'];

    public function getUrlAttribute()
    {
        return $this->profile->url;
    }
}
```

Which would produce the expected results, you still need to have included the Profile model for performance optimizations.

```
    return Social::with('profile')->get();

    {
        "id": 4,
        "url": the url from profiles table
        "profile": { ... }
    },
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I already had the Model but didn't think of using it like that. `Social::with(profiles)` works exactly as you mentionned, but while performing the second code I had this error `unexpected '$appends'`. And I was curious if it's possible that I retrieve profile's data by adding an `->select` ? Thank you.

Comment: Updated my answer with the appends, it is possible, but using eloquent model is more laravel way, if you want to i can write up an example tomorrow :)

Comment: I tried `protected $appends = ['url'];` instead and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Although  `"profile": { ... }` will always be showing right ?

Comment: I never been in the case where i had to hide a relationship, but with columns you can do protected $hidden = ['profile']; so maybe try a seen if it works for relationships?

Comment: I see. I just wanted to know that's it, it doesn't bother me whether it's present or not.

Comment: Personally i would also go with solution 1 with the nested url but that is me :)

Comment: I agree. But somehow I couldn't retrieve `url` from `profile`, it kept saying `url` is non existent in the table. In my controller I was putting something like `->where('url','=',$id)` when I was having that error.